# Double integral setting up

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is the integral I want to calculate.

[image]

I want to integrate over this range:

[image]

So I set up this integral:

[image]

However this gives me the wrong answer. Correct answer is:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: $x^2<x^3\Rightarrow x>1$

Comment: Pleas don't rely on images. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation